# Angular 6 service worker and routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-service-worker

I have an Angular 6 app which is working fine but only until I have published an update.

The service worker is requesting an old version of the runtime[hash].js script. Is this normal? My understanding is that the service worker should request the scripts as defined in the ngsw.config and use the hash table therein to determine if a request for a resource from the server is necessary.

Also, my (simplified) app routing is as follows:

```
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
}, 
{
    path: 'logout',
    component: LogoutComponent
}, 
{
    path: 'error',
    component: ErrorComponent
}, 
{
    path: '**',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
```

This seems to compound the problem as the catch-all route that directs to the 'PageNotFoundComponent' seems to come into play. For example, if I request a script that doesn't exist, I get the PageNotFoundComponent.

This causes an unexpected token '<' error in the browser (I presume from where a script tag is actually expecting some script and not the html of the 404 page).

Why does the angular routing seem to be playing a part here? If I request a script that exists, I get the script content returned (so seemingly not affected by the routing) but only when it doesn't do I get the 404 page.

**edit**
Just to add, I'm attaching the response from the request to ngsw.json. This shows the hash table of the scripts / resources. In there I only see the one, latest copy of the runtime.js.

[image]

Comment: How, or in what way, do you request a script file?

Comment: I was viewing source and opening the url in the script src attribute in a new tab. If I change the URL to be something non-existent, that’s when I see the PageNotFoundComponent

Comment: Yes, of course. What is your HTTP request setting of your web server/container? Do you point everything to index.html of Angular app?

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand your question. Could you rephrase please?

Comment: Did you forward all requests to Angular entry point, e.g. 'index.html'? If you host you API and Angular app together, in order to let Angular Router take control, you will need to configure redirection on all/part of HTTP request. e.g. /controller1/action1, here, server side will handle this and forward it to 'index.html' instead. Afterward, Angular Route will look it up and render the correct component. That is what I am thinking your problem is as requesting *.js or *.css was handled by Angular Route, not server side to serve the file resource.